# At what point is session data available?

Tags: php, session

I have the following so far opening a session (php),

```
session_start() ;

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
    $alert .= '<br/>' . '['.$key.']='.$value ;
}

$alert .= '<br/>$_SERVER[MY_SERVER...]='.$_SERVER['MY_SERVER_GENERATED'] ;

if($_SESSION['MY_SERVER_GENERATED'] !== true ||
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $_SESSION['PREV_REMOTEADDR'] ||
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] !== $_SESSION['PREV_USERAGENT']){
        $alert .= 'session destroyed' ;
        session_destroy() ;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['CREATED']) && (strtotime('now') - $_SESSION['CREATED']) > 300){//Delete expired sessions - seconds
    $alert .= '<div class="error_box">Your session has expired!</div>' ;
    $_SESSION = array() ;
}

session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = strtotime('now') ;
$_SESSION['MY_SERVER_GENERATED'] = true ;
$_SESSION['PREV_USERAGENT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ;
$_SESSION['PREV_REMOTEADDR'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;

echo $alert ;
```

The problem is the session is being destroyed everytime. $_SESSION is simply empty. At what point is it available to run checks like above?

Oops forgot to specifiy that I have verified the session is holding data but not until the page has been started. So the session is being destroyed because the $_SESSION data is all null and so the conditions are evaluating to false. As an example $alert does not register as having anything stored in it.

Comment: try to check the session_lifetime in your php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have a catch 22:

```
session_start() ;


if(!$_SESSION['MY_SERVER_GENERATED']){ <------- this will always be true 
                                                for a fresh session, so
    session_destroy() ;  <--------------------- this will always be executed
```

your session data never has a chance to populate.

Comment: @Magic the condition will match if the variable is false *or* if it is not set at all, which will always be true at first. If you want to check it for the value *false* and nothing else, do `if ($_SESSION['MY_SERVER_GENERATED'] !== false)`

Comment: I update the code to show exactly what I have at present. All the $_SESSION variables needed for this are set for it after regenerate_id  but $_SESSION is still coming up empty everytime the code is run. Is there a certain point where $_SESSION data becomes available?

Comment: @Magic as far as I can see, you still seem to be destroying the session before the values get set, leading to the values getting set nowhere. In the first request, your first `if` condition will always evaluate to true

Comment: ok I figured it out based on your response. I was under the false impression that session_regenerate_id would actually create a new session based on the old one and only the old session would be destroyed. What I needed was to use a whole new session_start after I destroyed the old session.